# Understanding React useEffect functions

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to understand how to call Flask APIs in React. Currently, I have this function defined in the `App()` function within my `App.js` file:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/').then(response =>
      response.json().then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
      )
  }, [])
```

I don't have much experience with JavaScript and I know that React's JSX can be confusing, so I'm hoping someone can clarify my understanding of this function.

#### What I think this means:

1. On startup (indicated by []), call this JS function (as indicated by the {} brackets) that has no input as indicated by the first set of empty parentheses ()
2. From the flask application, call the endpoint with the route indicated
3. Take this response (which we have *named* response?), and run the `json()` method to read the body as json
4. The result (which we have *named* data?) is then logged in the console. The curly brackets here again denoting that this is JS(X) code

Is this correct? Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Your understanding is correct except for that fact that this has nothing to do with JSX.  This is just plain JavaScript code inside a React `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I see - I'll have to read more about JSX. Thank you for the clarification! If you'd like to put that in an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted

Comment: Honestly, this question should probably be deleted instead of answered.  The question itself is asking about JSX, but turns out to have nothing to do with it.  The rest of the question is just outlining what JavaScript code does without asking anything.

Comment: JSX is JS (**J**ava**S**cript) + **X**ML (e.g. HTML). So basically the `return <span>hey</span>` stuff. What you are talking about is a so called "hook" which is a design pattern used in react. You may want to read more about hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: @David while what you say is true, I think we should help them with what they actually want to ask and then close the question. Otherwise, no one learned anything and we just have one more frustrated user not using this amazing platform.

Comment: I can delete it or try to transform it into a question that other people would find value in. Just let me know what would be best

Comment: @WhoDatBoy I think the main issue is that you don't understand what term refers to what. I would suggest you try some react getting started guides, [like this offical one](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) until you can ask a specific question :)

Comment: --> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343524

Comment: @Elias thank you for the suggestion! I'll take a look at that now

Comment: @KevinB thanks for that resource - I will ask a more "answerable" question in the future if that makes sense. Is the consensus that this should be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On startup (indicated by []), call this JS function (as indicated by the {} brackets) that has no input as indicated by the first set of empty parentheses ()

Pretty much correct. But it's important to know why `[]` means "on startup"

`useEffect` takes two arguments. A function to run and a list of dependencies to watch. After any of the dependencies have changed,  the function is re-run immediately afterward. The fact that dependencies is an empty array means that it will only ever run once, immediately after the first render, because none of the dependencies could possibly change.

> From the flask application, call the endpoint with the route indicated.

Not sure what flask is, but this makes a request to the `/` path on the domain that this react application is being served on.

> Take this response (which we have named response?), and run the json() method to read the body as json

`fetch` returns a promise that will eventually resolve. You call `then` on that function to provide a function that is called when that promise resolved. That function takes an argument that is the value of the resolved promise. You can name it anything you like, just like any javascript function argument.

> The result (which we have named data?) is then logged in the console. The curly brackets here again denoting that this is JS(X) code

Here `response.json` returns another promise that waits for the reponse data to be parsed as JSON. You call `then` on that new promise to handle that completion.

I'm not sure what curly brackets you mean, but this is simply a javascript data structure. The only `{}` in this posted code declare the bodies of functions.

---

There is no JSX in your code. Only plain javascript that calls function provided by React.

JSX is characterized by angle brackets, for example:

```
<div>{someJavascriptvariableHere}</div>
```

Would be JSX.

Comment: Ahhh I see how JSX is different now. By Flask I meant the Flask API that I am trying to interact with. This answer really helped clarify how `useEffect` works! I guess I just have one follow up question then - why, if `useEffect` has no dependencies, is it even run on startup? I would think there would have to be a special object to indicate this. Or is it literally just because when App.js is executed that the lines which define the dependency-free `useEffect` are run sequentially before reaching the `return` of `App()`? I hope this makes sense

Comment: Clean answer, actually helping, even if the question isn't perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: @WhoDatBoy yes, use effect is always ran at least once :) https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @WhoDatBoy every effect is executed after the first render, no matter what. The dependencies just change on which future renders it will execute after. That logic is very simple and consistent.